# Ruby on Rails - CSV file not storing to file path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a file path but i don't know how do i store the csv file to file path and i tried code below but i didn't get file from that file-path.I want uploaded csv file store to some location

```
File.join(file-path, filename)
```

Comment: Can you give some more details? How do you generate the file? Where?

Comment: I gave a option to user upload a csv file so user uploaded a file so i got file only i won't read that file.did you understand?

Comment: `file-path` is not a valid variable name in ruby

Comment: No, did not understand. Show some code.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to open CSV there a couple options but the code above has a syntactic error.

you can try this:

```
parsed_file = CSV.parse(File.open('/Users/yourname/Desktop/' + 'file.csv', 'wb'))

parsed_file.each do |row|
  puts row[0] # will print first column of each row
end
```